# PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 Objective-C implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hmac, sha256, pbkdf2

Can someone point me to an implementation of PBKDF2 using HMAC-SHA256 to generate a key, in Objective-C.  This is part of the key generation process that I will later use for AES-CBC-Pad encryption.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526853/how-to-create-pbkdf2-key-on-ios-device

Comment: I asked my question long before his.  So he really duplicated mine.  But yes, his question does offer more answers.

Comment: Everything you need is in the CommonCrypto framework although you might have to hunt around. The documentation isn't great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just simply borrow C implementation from OpenSSL or any other library.

Comment: Thanks.  I did just that actually.