# How to create PBKDF2 key on iOS device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, encryption

I need to create a PBKDF2 key to use in my AES encryption routine in my iPhone Xcode application.  I have seen references to using OpenSSL to do this, but not found specific references to what module within OpenSSL to call.

I have scanned various OpenSSL .h files searching for a means to make this call, but have so far been unsuccessful.

The key I will be using is 5-digits, Salt is 12 characters, Iterations is 1000, and I need a 128-bit generated key.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1()` function in `openssl/evp.h`.  Divining how to use the function is pretty easy from the declaration:

```
int PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(const char *pass, int passlen,
               const unsigned char *salt, int saltlen, int iter,
               int keylen, unsigned char *out);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [p5_crpt2.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-12/openssl/crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c) is what you are looking for.